# Implementing extract refactoring on Xtext

Tags: refactoring, extract, inline, jface, xtext

How can I implement refactoring such as extract and inline on Xtext?

I found this post, but I'm not sure how to use the jface API for that.
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1068262/

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't say for which language you wanted to refactor.  But in general, you're going need at least name and type resolution ("symbol tables" etc.) and Xtext does not provide any specific help here, so you are likely to have to provide this yourself.  Building symbol tables for a modern language is actually pretty hard; all the rules about scopes and lookups have gotten complex for Java, C++ and C#.

Comment: did you have a look at what xtend does? xtext-xtend/org.eclipse.xtend.ide/src/org/eclipse/xtend/ide/refactoring/ExtractMethodHandler.java

Comment: @ChristianDietrich where can I find this library? I found this git https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-xtend but how do I integrate it with my xtext project?

Comment: not integrate. let you inspire (copy & paste & adapt) by it

Comment: Thank you. It would probably take some time to adjust (lots of packages are missing from Xtext). I'll update.